# Wrong and weird inserted page numbers and highlighted in pink color for installed fonts

Tags: adobe-indesign, numbering

Today I found out when I insert a page number under `right-click < Insert Special Characters < Markers < Current Page Number`. **InDesign** doesn't show proper signs (e.g "A" symbol for a `Master Page` and also for the `Pages`). Just shows the weird signs or double "SS" letters (the screenshots). Also, It highlighted in ***pink*** color while those fonts were installed on my system.

I tried all kinds of fonts (Latin or Farsi/Persian fonts), All of them give me the same results.
`Find/Replace Font window`(under `Type` menu) is okay with the fonts and doesn't show any missing ones. I should say this issue is just happening when I insert a page number, while I draw a text box and type or paste a piece of text (in Latin or Persian texts), no issues happen and it's okay and I can type or paste form *MS Word*, *web pages* properly.

The **Adobe InDesign** version I have is CC 15.1 x64 (not trial) and also support right-to-left languages like Persian, Arabic, and Hebrew and I had no problems with page numbers before and was okay, but after a while, I back to work with it, I found out this confusing problem.

As you see in the below screenshot the page number in both `Master Pages` and the `Pages` are the same and fill page number text boxes with those weird signs instead of with the proper prefix of a `Master Pages` like A, B, C, ... and the `Pages` with 2, 3,....,20, 21 or whatever.

Restarting **Adobe InDesign** doesn't work as well. This issue happens in the documents I created before and in the newly created blank documents. All fonts I need and apply for a document are installed and exist (no fonts are missing). Also for a test, I select a text box of a page number in the `Master Page` and try it with all fonts that are installed on my machine, but nothing is fixed.

[image]

[image]

#### UPDATED (9/5/2021)

I updated **Adobe InDesign** to the latest version (16.4) and reinstall Farsi fonts on my system, now page numbers in the `Pages` show correctly like before, but still, the page number in `Master Page` doesn't show with the related prefix and colored in the *pink* background (First screenshot in above).

There's no problem with Latin fonts in both `Master Page` and the `Pages`, each prefix letter in `Master Page` and numbers in the `Pages` show properly.

Regardless of the *pink* background ([substitute characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character)) for Farsi fonts JUST in `Master Page`, I can see correct pages numbers in the pages and do my job.

Comment: It's not a weird symbol. That's a missing glyph symbol. It means the font you have chosen doesn't contain the glyph you want to use.

Comment: @BillyKerr, but the font used to right and showed properly. Also as I said I tried with all fonts as a test for both Latin and Farsi Languages. I didn't choose a rare special glyph, just numbers for page numbers. If I type and insert numbers, they appear as I expect without any problem, but insert numbers with the "Current Page Number" feature of InDesign with the same font, don't work and get those symbols or a pair of "S" letters like this: "SS"!

Comment: "I tried with all fonts".. you mean, literally every font… every. single. font? Did you try [Noto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts)??? What you seem to have is a font substitution issue, which may be Adobe's fault, or it may be your OS. We don't have enough detail to guess, but a re-install [overlay, not replace] of the OS will usually fix things like that.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Yes, actually I mean every single font I have in the Font folder in my Windows OS. I'd like to download Noto fonts, but the size is pretty huge (1.1 GB!) for my connection speed, and never heard about it before, maybe it works, but previously I used every font for page numbering without a problem and showed correctly, and now I need to apply a few Farsi fonts to a document that worked properly. Now no fonts work well! Maybe InDesign needs to be updated to the 2021 version. Try to update tomorrow and see what will happen after that and say here if anything changes or not.

Comment: I think this is a *localized* issue and that is off topic. We can't solve local troubleshooting issues here. It's clearly some issue with fonts or settings on *your* system.

Comment: @Scott, Unsure, and maybe it is an issue that comes from my system, as I updated my question, after updating Adobe InDesign, now in Farsi/Persian documents, page numbers in the "Pages" now show properly, but in "Master Page". In Latin documents both are fine.

Comment: @MasoudMoghaddam - sounds like your next step might be to contact Adobe and report this problem, or perhaps check if it's already a known bug when using Farsi text.

Comment: Also note that Arabic style numbers in Arabic fonts may not be the same glyphs as numbers in Latin fonts. In Noto Sans Arabic for example. The Latin style numbers begin at U+0030.  But the Arabic style numbers start at U+0660. So, essentially the font has both Latin and Arabic style numbers. Perhaps the font you are trying to use doesn't have the Latin style numbers at all, and is just displaying them as missing glyphs.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I think like you Billy about the lack of glyph in Farsi fonts in compare Latin fonts. Also, I installed the previous Adobe InDesign (15.1) that the problem happens in it, and the issue happens again and remain, while in the latest version of Adobe InDesign (16.4) that I received today, everything is okay, except the page number in the "Master" page for the Farsi font; as I said. I agree with you Billy; to report it to Adobe support. Maybe it's a bug or lack of glyph for a non-standard less known Farsi font.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I asked my question in the Adobe community as well. [https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/weird-signs-for-numbers-with-pink-background-while-the-font-is-exist-on-my-system/m-p/12366528#M444073], and you're right about the absent _glyph(s)_ to show proper page numbers in my **Farsi fonts**, and two _"SS"_ signs; seems caused by a bug in ID 15.1 that was fixed in _15.1.3_. BillyKerr, you can answer my question to close this topic; so I'll give you a green mark! Thank you!

Comment: We aren't really supposed to answer tech support questions here Masoud, since they're off-topic. Sorry about that. But anyway, I'm glad you've made progress finding out what the problem might be.